# Volume control in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I was wondering if there was a way to control the volume in pygame? Currently I am just importing my mp3 `pygame.mixer.Sound("My sound.MP3")` and then running my sound with `pygame.mixer.Sound.play()` which works fine but I want to control the volume in my script rather than having to go through my volume settings.

Comment: Look towards [`pygame.mixer.Channel`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel), it has `.set_volume` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pygame.mixer.Sound`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) object has a [`set_volume(value)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.set_volume) method:

> This will set the playback volume (loudness) for this Sound. This will immediately affect the Sound if it is playing. It will also affect any future playback of this Sound.
>
> Parameters:    value (float) --
> volume in the range of 0.0 to 1.0 (inclusive)

```py
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound("My sound.MP3")
my_sound.play()
my_sound.set_volume(0.5)
```